# Using if/else operator in php code

Tags: php, if-statement

here's my question:

i have the folwing code in my project:

```
$news = "Article 20.part2";

if(strpos($news,'.part1')) {$news_n = ".part1";}
else if(strpos($news,'.part2')) {$news_n = ".part2";}
else if(strpos($news,'.part3')) {$news_n = ".part3";}
else if(strpos($news,'.part4')) {$news_n = ".part4";}
else if(strpos($news,'.part5')) {$news_n = ".part5";}

echo $news;
echo "Part number:" . $news_n . "- <a href=\"#\">Read more</a>";
```

What i want is to display the number of the news part, but the problem is that there are articles with +20/+30 parts and i don't want to add

```
else if(strpos($news,'.part20')) {$news_n = ".part20";}
```

etc to my code.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
for($i=1;$i<100;$i++)
{
    if(strpos($news,'.part'.$i)) 
        $news_n = '.part'.$i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [PHP preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) for this

```
$news = "Article 20.part20";
$matches= array();
if (preg_match("/\.part(\d*)/", $news,$matches)){
    $news_n = '.part'. $matches[1];
}

echo $news;
echo "Part number:" . $news_n . "- <a href=\"#\">Read more</a>";
```

**Edit:** You can also use `$new_n = $matches[0];`. `$matches[0]` gives you the full match and `$matches[1]` will have the number part.

**Edit2:** If the .part is the going to be the last item, then you can use much simpler [strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

```
$news = "Article 20.part20";
$news_n = strstr($news, ".part");   
echo $news;
echo "Part number:" . $news_n . "- <a href=\"#\">Read more</a>";
```

Comment: This is the best solution, but maybe he need to think about loops before go to regexp

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression

```
$matches=[];
if (preg_match_all('.part\[( ^[0-9]{1,3}$)\]/', $news, $matches)) {
print_r($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string you are looking for is numbered based as you say in your question you can do:

```
foreach(range(1, 50) as $i) {
    $part = sprintf('.part%d', $i);
    if(strpos($news, $part) {
        $news_n = sprintf('.%s', $part);
    }
}
```